# Under what circumstances in Colorado can a judge sentence below a mandatory minimal sentence?

Tags: judge, colorado, sentencing, judicial-review, judiciary

The facts around the case of Rogel Aguilera-Mederos seem pretty clear cut, however unfair.

- A jury found him guilty
- The judge didn't want to sentence him to 110 years.
- The judge had to sentence him to 110 years because it was the mandatory minimal sentence.

[Now I'm reading in the news](https://www.aljazeera.com/news/2021/12/27/us-judge-to-reconsider-trucker-110-year-sentence?fbclid=IwAR249K-Tyk-eub36bApjohj1rgwfkkuc8u-fiJmHeeq7Z5NboySOCGjCNBc&sf157318016=1&sf157315922=1)

> A judge in the US state of Colorado is set to consider on Monday a **request from prosecutors to reduce the 110-year prison sentence of a truck driver**...

How can a judge reduce a sentence below a mandatory minimum?  Shy of being granted clemency or an act of the legislature is there anything that can happen here?

---

[Follow up question, *"What happens if a judge disregards a mandatory minimal sentencing law?"*](https://law.stackexchange.com/q/76583/218)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Who decides when those conditions are met?** (*taken from the OP's comment*.)

According to [§ 18-1.3-406. Mandatory sentences for violent crimes - definitions](https://law.justia.com/codes/colorado/2018/title-18/article-1.3/part-4/section-18-1.3-406/) of the Colorado Criminal Code:

> ...within ninety-one days after he or she has been placed in the custody of the department of corrections, **the department shall transmit to the sentencing court a report on the evaluation and diagnosis of the violent offender,** and the court, in a case which it considers to be exceptional and to involve unusual and extenuating circumstances, **may thereupon modify the sentence, effective not earlier than one hundred nineteen days** after his or her placement in the custody of the department...

Answer (score 0):

From the article:

> Colorado law allows for sentences for crimes deemed violent to be modified in cases with “unusual and extenuating circumstances”, but those sentences cannot take effect until 119 days after a person enters prison.

Comment: First, I didn't see that. I didn't see below they obnoxious break in the page that says "Continue Reading" and lists other articles, that other articles were continued. So thanks. Second, so what is the point of a minimum sentence? I'm confused just to set a floor of 119 days? Who decides when those conditions are met? And to the original question what happens if a judge sentences under the minimimal sentence? Did he commit a crime? Is his sentence final?

Comment: @Evan Carroll Why did you downvote his answer? He answered your question. You _did_ see that 119 days, you just couldn’t read it.

Comment: @kisspuska I did not downvote his answer. (I also didn't upvote it).